# What does "aggregated" mean in this context? aggregated=False? (Python)

Tags: python, linked-list

Looking over assignments and practice we were working with Linked Lists and we were provided with the following code :

`

```
class LinkedList:
    class ListNode:
        def __init__(self, data=None):
            self.next = None
            self.prev = None
            self.data = data
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.count = 0
        self.char_count = 0
    def append(self, data):
        n = LinkedList.ListNode(data)
        if self.first is None:         # Special case for empty lists
            self.first = n
            self.last = n
        else:  # Add the node to the end.
            n.prev = self.last    # the old .last becomes the new nodes previous
            self.last.next = n    # the old .last needs it's next to point to thenew node
            self.last = n         # point the .last node to be the new node.
            self.count += 1
    def size(self):
        return self.count
    def iter(self):
        curr = self.first
        while curr:
            ret = curr.data
            curr = curr.next
            yield ret
    def delete(self, data):
        curr = self.first
        deleted_fl = False
        if curr is None:  # LIST IS EMPTY, TRIVIAL CASE
            deleted_fl = False
        elif curr.data == data:  # REMOVE FROM FRONT
            if self.first == self.last:  # IF REMOVING THE FIRST AND ONLY NODE
                self.last = None
            self.first = curr.next
            deleted_fl = True
        elif self.last.data == data:  #REMOVE FROM END
            self.last = self.last.prev
            self.last.next = None
            deleted_fl = True
        else:  # SEARCH THE REST TO SEE IF IT MATCHES
            while curr:
                if curr.data == data:
                    curr.prev.next = curr.next
                    curr.next.prev = curr.prev
                    deleted_fl = True
                    break
                curr = curr.next
        if deleted_fl:
            self.count -= 1
    def contains(self, data):
        for n in self.iter():
            if data == n:
                return True
        return False
    def search(self, data):
        curr = self.first
        while curr:
            if curr.data == data:
                return curr
            curr = curr.next
        return None
    def clear(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
```

`

Then we were asked to implement some functions. This is one of them:

```
def charCount(self, aggregated=False):
```

**the definition:**

```
 Returns the total number of characters contained in the nodes of the 
linked list.
         If the `aggregated' argument is True, the result should be a single 
integer
         representing the sum of character counts of all elements in the 
LinkedList.  If False,
         the result should be a list of integers representing the count of 
characters of each
         node.  In both cases, if the list is empty, return `None'.  The aggregated
version of
         this method should be O(1) and the dis-aggregated version should be O(n).
         :param aggregated: If True, aggregate the counts into a single value. If 
False, return
         a list of counts.
         :return: A single integer or list of integers as described above.
```

What in the world is aggregated=False supposed to mean here? What is meant by "if the aggregated argument is True"?

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aggregated` is an argument of the function that you can pass when calling the function. E.g. you could call the function like this:

```python
list = LinkedList()
list.charCount(True)
```

In this case, the value of the `aggregated` argument that you passed is `True`.

The `=False` part in the function declaration means that you don't **have to** pass a value for the `aggregated` argument, and in that case it will default to `False`. It's a so-called [default argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Comment: You're welcome @KitsuneBliss. If that answers your question, make sure to mark it as "accepted" (by clicking on the checkmark on the of the answer), so that other users know it's been resolved.